# How to generate dynamic report for sum of data columns from a table where column are the same using php

Tags: php

stock_entries 
stockid  supplier    item    total   payment   balance
   1      john      iphone    100      10        90
   2     charles     itel      50      40        10
   3      john       ipad     500     250       250
   4      alex      tecno      20      20         0
   5     charles    ipad       30      0         30

I want to generate a report which will show me the total_balance for each supplier.
For instance; for john the system will automatically check the stock_entries table where supplier column is john then sum the balance found for john in balance column. For john: 90+250=380 where 380=sum(balance) where supplier column is john.  The same thing for each supplier found in stock_entries table.
I want to get a dynamic report like this:
Supplier    total_balance
 John             380
Charles            40
 Alex               0

Note:
Total_balance in report is the sum of balance column from the stock_entries table where supplier name are the same

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you only use php or some sql also? And please make your code more readable....

Answer (score 0):

CREATE VIEW supplier_detailsSum
AS
SELECT supplier_details.supplier_name,

```
   1.0 * SUM(COALESCE(stock_entries.balance, 0))/2  AS balance
```

FROM   supplier_details
       LEFT JOIN stock_entries
       ON stock_entries.stock_supplier_name=supplier_details.supplier_name
GROUP BY supplier_details.supplier_name;